# How to try Ubuntu on a hp pavilion g7-1246ef computer that has no Linux suport for video card? (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, 64-bit, display, live-usb

I want to try Ubuntu on a hp pavilion g7-1246ef computer. I got it as a 64 bit system with a win7 64 bit but now it runs a 32 bit win 7 (due to canon printer driver issue).

The Windows device manager displays:

[image]

I have created a live USB and then CD of Lubuntu 12.04, a live usb of Ubuntu 12.04 (all 32 bit),  and tried to boot in each of them, set to boot from usb, reached the page with `try ubuntu` but then selecting it nothing happened, or so it seemed: in fact using a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 live usb I was first under the same impression but when I pushed power off I realized a window was barely visible on an almost black display, and even folder icons were there but almost invisible.

I guess there are no video drivers for this system.

[image]

Is there a solution?

---

[This is a late edit just to put things right for reference: **even without [nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/a/207177/47206) and without the proprietary driver, my machine would still work: just that the startup luminosity level was zero and had to put it up manually**.] (I do not currently use ubuntu/linux on that machine, was just interested for a solution in such cases.)

---

### UPDATE for 14.04

With the new 3.13 kernel that video card is now well supported - more details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/536842/47206) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/469439/47206).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems(from your image) that you have a Radeon graphics card...
This may be the problem

When you reach to try Ubuntu page, press F6 and select
**nomodeset** option and then select Try Ubuntu and hit enter...
Ubuntu will run the setup with basic Graphics.
Then you'll be able to try/install Ubuntu...

While using a live USB boot, the `try ubuntu` page may have other options (e.g.use tab to edit): you have to edit so as to add   `nomodeset` there: it has to look like that: `quiet splash nomodeset`

Then, continue to try ubuntu or install.

Hope that works :)

Cheers!

Comment: it works perfectly, but only in live cd, not in usb, or i'm not able to find that `nomodset` command in usb. *can you advise me ?* As for the rest i see no loss in display quality with `nomodset` although it gives me some errors on a `no hardware response`. i  would prefer just to use ubuntu on this one from  a live usb as the cd is noisy

Comment: here might be the answer (have not tried it yet) http://askubuntu.com/q/147779/47206

Comment: When you get to the menu after booting from USB, There  will be some options to edit the entries like "press 'e' to edit..."

After doing so find the words: "quiet splash" and type nomodeset before quiet splash so it becomes: "nomodeset quiet splash" (Without quotes) then press Ctr + x (or F10) to boot :)

Comment: it also worked for me as in the edit that i made to your answer: `quiet splash nomodeset`