# How to run commands from a bash file the way they run from terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Sorry for my probably very naive question.

What I mean is: how to create an executable script/bash file that would run more complex commands, commands which must normally be put in a terminal?

Specifically, I am referring to the following commands:

- Learned about it from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/469439/47206):

> ```
> DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info
> ```

That would start `glxgears` and put to work the ATI discrete card. Then I can monitor its temperature etc. But when I run it from terminal, I get this:

[image]

While when I run it with the script

```
#!/bin/bash

DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info
```

only the gears window is visible, not the other one with text.

I would like to be able to use a bash file and have the first result, and then run the file from a launcher.

---

Considering [this page on `aria2` and `webgui-aria2`](http://truongtx.me/2013/11/12/aria2-as-default-download-manager/), `aria2` is started in that context by running in terminal a long command:

```
touch /path/to/download/folder/session.txt && aria2c --enable-rpc --rpc-listen-all --save-session=/path/to/download/folder/session.txt --input-file=/path/to/download/folder/session.txt -x16 -s16 -k1M --dir=/path/to/download/folder
```

How to run that with a script (that I would then execute from a launcher) and have the same result, the same info?

A script like so (adapted to my download folder)

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /home/cip/Downloads/aria2/session.txt && aria2c --enable-rpc --rpc-listen-all --save-session=/home/cip/Downloads/aria2/session.txt --input-file=/home/cip/Downloads/aria2/session.txt -x16 -s16 -k1M --dir=/home/cip/Downloads/aria2
```

gives nothing, while thhe programs starts.

(I'm in Xubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Regarding the second part, see http://askubuntu.com/q/141229/158442.

Comment: How did you run the `glxgears` script? You could create a launcher for that too, and set `Terminal=true` in it.

Comment: @muru - i think that question is about how to put already existing scripts in launchers, and that i know already. while i ask is how to put long commands in scripts: commands that i can run in terminal but i do not know how to add in a bash file

Comment: What does the length have to do with anything? You'd put that in a script the same way you have done with the `glxgears` script.

Comment: @muru - i realize how odd that sounds and naive. but i do not know how exactly to add `Terminal=true` in that script :) :(

Comment: @muru - i will add to question what i tried with that long one

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. You add `Terminal=true` in a .desktop file (the launcher you create for the script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this script (saved as `/home/muru/test.sh`):

```
#! /bin/bash
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info
```

A basic launcher for this would look like (say, save it as `/home/muru/test.desktop`):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=glx-gears-info
Exec=/home/muru/test.sh
```

Make them both executable:

```
chmod +x test.sh test.desktop
```

Now you should have these two entries in your home folder:
[image]

Notice how the name is `glx-gears-info` even though the launcher's filename is `test.desktop`. You can double click on it to start the script:
[image]

---

For a script like (say, located at `/home/muru/start-aria.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /home/cip/Downloads/aria2/session.txt && \
    aria2c --enable-rpc --rpc-listen-all \
       --save-session=/home/cip/Downloads/aria2/session.txt \
       --input-file=/home/cip/Downloads/aria2/session.txt -x16 -s16 -k1M \
       --dir=/home/cip/Downloads/aria2
```

(I split the command into multiple lines for readability) the launcher file would look like (say `/home/muru/start-aria.desktop`):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Start Aria2
Exec=/home/muru/start-aria.sh
```

You can set `Terminal=false` here as this command probably doesn't need a terminal.

---

To get the terminal window when using Xfce launchers, tick 'Run in Terminal'.

[image]

A second command, that would **close** aria2, can be added in the same Xfce launcher: `pkill aria2c`

Also:

- by adding them into a single launcher,
- setting advanced properties like in the image below

[image]

(namely 'show last used item' and 'inside button'),

- and adding two specific icons,

***the launcher will always display the current status of aria2: running or closed***.

[image]

Comment: @cipricus Thanks for the edits. Which Launcher editor is that?

Comment: it's the Xfce panel launcher. it allows multiple 'shortcuts' into one launcher, which is handy for many purposes: creating category launcher (like multimedia or internet browsers), or different options for the same application like in the situation above (also: multiple chromium or firefox accounts into one launcher etc)

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DRI_PRIME=1
xfce4-terminal --window -H -x glxgears -info
```

Don't know if all the switches are needed, but it worked.

Comment: @muru - that works. the longer one can be used in the same way, aria2 **starts**, but with a different window than when run in terminal. i will edit the question with detail. maybe i will get farther progress