# Making amd/intel GPUs Switchable On Laptop

Tags: drivers, hybrid-graphics, vga, vgaswitcheroo, switchable-graphics

I tried using few different distros on this laptop in last few years. I really like linux and want to use it in every day use but I have all sorts of problems on my laptop lenovo g500. Yesterday I finally decided to install it and make it work. For now I can't figure out how to make my hibrid gpu's switchable and I can't change my mac without breaking wifi totally (wifi just refuses to work even if I take it down via ifconfig, or even stopping the network-manager service, change mac, restart, still won't work). So I am hoping people here can help me.

---

**First off, making hybrid GPUs switchable**. I have integrated **INTEL** and discrete **AMD** gpu.

I followed [HybridGraphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) guide but when I try to echo any parameter to

```
/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

for example

```
sudo echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Whatever parameter I use IGD/DIS/ON/OFF etc. Nothing happens.

---

Here's some info (command-result):

```
lspci -nn
```

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0156] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e59] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8570A/8570M] [1002:6663] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

---

```
sensors
```

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +511.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +53.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 0:         +48.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:         +51.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

---

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0
```

NOTE: "DIS" gpu was DynOff until I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/700567) guide 
Hello, I tried using few different distros on this laptop in last few years. I really like linux and want to use it in every day use but I have all sorts of problems on my laptop lenovo g500. Yesterday I finally decided to install it and make it work. For now I can't figure out how to make my hibrid gpu's switchable and I can't change my mac without breaking wifi totally (wifi just refuses to work even if I take it down via ifconfig, or even stopping the network-manager service, change mac, restart, still won't work). So I am hoping people here can help me.

---

**First off, making hybrid GPUs switchable**. I have integrated **INTEL** and discrete **AMD** gpu.

I followed [HybridGraphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) guide but when I try to echo any parameter to

```
/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

for example

```
sudo echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Whatever parameter I use IGD/DIS/ON/OFF etc. Nothing happens.

---

Here's some info (command-result):

```
lspci -nn
```

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0156] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e59] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8570A/8570M] [1002:6663] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

---

```
sensors
```

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +511.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +53.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 0:         +48.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:         +51.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

---

sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0
```

NOTE: "DIS" gpu was DynOff until I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/700567) guide

---

I am thinking that something might be wrong or that there simply is no driver for my amd gpu. But last year I think, I tried installing fglrx driver package and my ubuntu just keeps crashing then. Same with Fedora as well. Also when I check in "additional drivers" in system settings I am not getting any options for my amd card.

**I have switchable graphics enabled in BIOS.**
**I am using 16.04 ubuntu**

Comment: Are you using 16.04?

Comment: yes I am using LTS 16.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 and AMD graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-and-amd-graphics)

Comment: I don't think so. That user has a problem with AMD graphics only. I need to make switchable graphics work.

Comment: That is a Q&A by me explaining the whole situation of AMD graphics in 16.04. It doesn't matter if you have switchable or not. That answer will apply.

Comment: My bad then. I would like to hear your opinion on should I even bother making it work. Will it have that great impact on performance? I am using this laptop for daily programming and watching movies. Also it's not my main pc. What about just disabling the switchable graphics in BIOS and going with the integrated intel one? Also can I do anything with the gpu I am not using then?

Comment: If you have both cards enabled, Ubuntu will use Intel unless there are proprietary drivers installed for the discrete card. I don't know if there's anything you can use. If you do graphical stuff (movies will be fine with Intel), then you'll need to downgrade to 14.04.